# How to make an Excel sheet Allowing Unique Entries Making Others Red

Tags: excel

I am looking for an excel sheet with 2 columns -
1. Number
2. URL

If Paste 10 URLS Daily onto it and if today's URL exists previously, It should turn red.
That is all I require.

Thanks in Advance for taking time out and explaining.

Comment: Hi Pushkar Dua, welcome to StackOverflow! Please note, that SO is a platform to look for help with specific coding problems, not a code-this-for-me service. Describing what you tried so far or which options you had in mind is considered good manners. Maybe you want to edit your question to add this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Read [Apply conditional formatting in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/apply-conditional-formatting-in-excel-34402f91-c7e7-4060-944c-65d913033d18?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US), section **Highlight duplicate values with color**. It's exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only the second of the doubled URL should turn red and not the first (as shown in the picture) then use following formula in the conditional formatting (in my case applied to cell B5:B11)

```
=IF(B5="";FALSE;IF(ISNA(MATCH(B5;B$4:B4;0));FALSE;TRUE))
```

[image: Only the second of the doubled entry is marked red]